# Unexpected element {urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com}session Id during simple type deserialization

Tags: integration, soap-api, salesforce1-app

This is the request message:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>   
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
   xmlns:urn="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
  <soapenv:Header>
     <urn:SessionHeader>
        <urn:sessionId>
        00D5i0000014B8m!ARYAQLtoOXETtcvv2z3WkG32psiIiDDY8yJY1vHjTEZnVuT1NxbGarPJYtsLiPTHq3_U3jYLCcq6JvFggdaM2XXClEGIpA9h
        <urn:sessionId>
     </urn:SessionHeader>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
     <urn:query>
        <urn:queryString>SELECT id,Name FROM Account </urn:queryString>
     </urn:query>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This is the response:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault>
            <faultcode>soapenv:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Unexpected element {urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com}sessionId during simple type deserialization</faultstring>
        </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the closing tag for `<urn:sessionId>` in your code

Making the below change in your request would fix the error

```
    <urn:sessionId>
    00D5i0000014B8m!ARYAQLtoOXETtcvv2z3WkG32psiIiDDY8yJY1vHjTEZnVuT1NxbGarPJYtsLiPTHq3_U3jYLCcq6JvFggdaM2XXClEGIpA9h
    </urn:sessionId>
```